# Localize Facebook Issue

Tags: facebook, localization, translation

I'm making Website with Facebook Login.
Login works and it's awesome.
But recently I've faced the issue:
Main language is English.
When I try to add Localize -> Detailed description for French localization, I'm getting error:

> The native string on which the translation is based no longer exists.
>   There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later.

Though there's this value for English and it's even shown as placeholder for French.
Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found this:

[The detailed description won't change on localisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423325/the-detailed-description-wont-change-on-localisation)

It totally worked. Good luck!