# The detailed description won't change on localisation

Tags: localization

The problem appeared when I tried to save the locale-specific components. The detailed description stayed unchanged.

This was the notification that appeared: "Error
The native string on which the translation is based no longer exists.
There was a problem saving your changes. Please try again later."

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

On the same page (the translation page), click the "advanced options" at the top right. On the next screen, click the "Dashboard" tab (top left).

Now, on the top right hand side you'll see a link to "Delete and re-import all strings". Click it and then you should be able to save the changes for the translation.